# Proof, with function f being an injection that #A = #f(A) $\leq$ #B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Consider two non-empty sets A and B and function $f : A \rightarrow B $. 
Proof that when f is an injection, that $ \sharp A = \sharp f(A) \leq \sharp B$

I already thought of the following:

$$ \text{Define }  \tilde{f}: f(A) \rightarrow A : f(a) \rightarrow a$$
This way you prove that all a $\in$ A will be projected on themselves using 
$$ \tilde{f} \circ f $$
but i am not sure i am headed in the right direction.

I also need to prove that when f is a surjection $ \sharp A \geq \sharp f(A) = \sharp B$

Comment: If $f$ is injective then by definition every element of $A$ is mapped to a unique point in $B$ so there has to be more points in $B$ than $A$ and since every point in $A$ has to be mapped somewhere $#A = #f(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

If R subset S, then #R <= #S.
Since f us an injection, there is a bijection between A and B.
Thus #A = #f(A).  Since f(A) subset B, #A = #f(A) <= #B.

If f is a surjection, use the axiom of choice to construct
a bijection between some subset K of A and B.  Use that
bijection and the previous result to show #B <= #A.